# Java ~ Read external programs memory

Tags: java, memory, process

I have the following case:

I am writing a java program and I'd like to read inside of the memory of an external process (that is a process not started by my application)

Is this (easily) possible? Do I need to download external jar's?

Thanks!

Comment: Is the "external process" running on a different JVM? Do you have control over that process?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

yes, with Java Native Interface and Inter Process Communication: JNI allow you to call "C" native libraries, you must implement a module with "IPC:Shared Memory" in C. and modify others programs to work with Shared Memory.
But... you are developing the first layer of OSI, is better try with sockets or webservices.

Comment: I figured it out using JNA! But still thanks a lot!:P